# Why does this keep returning 'sorry' even though i have a predefined answer

Tags: python

```
answer = 5
guess = input("guess number between 1 and 10:  ")

if guess == answer:
    print('great job!')

elif guess != answer:
    print('sorry')

else:
    print('wrong')
```

Comment: It prints 'great job!' for me. the answer is 5 if the input is 5 it prints 'great job' else it will print 'sorry'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Btw your `elseif` and `else` logically civer the same cass so one is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: when i enter 5 it is printing 'sorry instead of 'great job'

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski but still not printing the 'great' instead  printing 'wrong'

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the object type.

here `answer` has object type of `int` while `guess` has object type of `str`, `input` function give object type of string, both are different.

to make it according to your need, you need to change the input object type.

so if you do `guess = int(input())`, your code will work accordingly